# Local Encrypted Incremental Space efficient Backup Solution

Tags: backup, debian, rsnapshot

I am a student and for my hobby projects i managed to buy a vps. Problem is how can i backup that? I have got a webdav account somewhere (and they allow to store any file types for any purposes as long as copyrights are not being voilated) and i have mounted webdav as /media/webdav.

My usual tbz2 backups site is around 300-400M and incremental backups vary from 20M to 120M. This is when i do them manually and download them on my laptop.

I am using Debian Lenny on the server and i am looking for a backup solution that makes full and incremental backups with encryption as i would store the backups on the webdav mount.

I tried duplicity, but its a bit complexed, but i have disabled root's ssh, and only root has access to most of the folders that i want to backup. So if possible please suggest a solution.

I have looked over rdiff-backup, rsnapshot, ftplicity, box backup and some others.

Finally decided Duplicity as the tool to go with.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will work with WebDAV, but you can try [Box Backup](http://www.boxbackup.org/). It does encrypted, incremental, space efficient backups quite well in our testing.

Comment: That looks like a very interesting project. Might have to try it myself.

Comment: seems complex setup to me, even though under debian i install server and client using apt-get...

Answer (score 1):

Brackup might fit your requirements.

http://code.google.com/p/brackup/

Comment: From http://www.openfusion.net/tags/brackup : "as soon as you start trying to brackup trees on any size you find that brackup aborts if it finds a file has changed between the time it initially walks the tree and when it comes to back it up."

And he solved it using LVM's snapshot, too bad, i dont have LVM.